# Scaffold For specific actions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can I generate a scaffold for only specific action?

```
rails g scaffold user name create destroy (but its not working as expected, it create all 7 standard actions)
```

I only want to generate through scaffold command.

Comment: Can you describe more clearly what you actually need and why you need only few actions as opposed to default ones?

Answer (score 2):

After looking into the docs and reading `rails g scaffold --help` and `rails g scaffold_controller --help` I come to the conclusion that what you want is **not** possible.

It makes some sense, since in Rails terms a scaffold controller is a RESTful controller, which implies that it creates those 7 standard actions so you can say `resources :users` in your routing file.

I think you just have to manually remove the unwanted actions, views and routing behaviour. Or perhaps better: just create everything from scratch or from a regular `rails g controller index show`-like command, and then fill in the blanks using copy/paste from some other scaffolded resource.